# How to count data(excluded records filtered in include 'model') using strongloop

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop

I am trying to join table **ABC** with **XYZ**, and count records in ABC (excluded records filtered in XYZ) using Strongloop.

My code is:

```
  ABC.count({where: {abcPropertyName: {neq: '0x0'}}, include: { relation: 'XYZ', scope: {where: {xyzPropertyName: 'someValue'}}}}).$promise.then(function (result) {
      $rootScope.CountRes= result.count;
  });
```

**Issue:** filter in 'xyz' is not working.Its count **all** records in ABC.